Parameterized Junit 5 with Sting array as source
I have a method that validate passwords. I have a JUnit for that. There I have an array with all possible kind of invalid password. I needed to parameterized the JUnit method using @MethodSource. I guess it should be a way parameterized using directly an String[], INVALID_PASSWORDS, and then I could get rid of the method invalidPasswords():
private static final String[] INVALID_PASSWORDS = { NON_DIGIT_PASSWORD, NON_SPECIAL_CHARACTER_PASSWORD,
        NON_LOWER_CASE_PASSWORD, NON_UPPER_CASE_PASSWORD, SHORTER_THAN_8_PASSWORD, WITH_WHITESPACES_PASSWORD };

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("invalidPasswords")
void When_invalidPassword_Expect_exceptionThrown(String value) {
    Assertions.assertThrows(InvalidRequest.class, () -> Password.of(value.toString()));
}

private static Stream<String> invalidPasswords() {
    return Arrays.stream(INVALID_PASSWORDS);
}

Any idea?

You can use
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(strings = { NON_DIGIT_PASSWORD, ... })
void When_invalidPassword_Expect_exceptionThrown(String value) {
    Assertions.assertThrows(InvalidRequest.class, () -> Password.of(value.toString()));
}

If you really want a field, you can use @FieldSource:
static final String[] INVALID_PASSWORDS = { NON_DIGIT_PASSWORD, ... };

@ParameterizedTest
@FieldSource("INVALID_PASSWORDS")
void When_invalidPassword_Expect_exceptionThrown(String value) {
    Assertions.assertThrows(InvalidRequest.class, () -> Password.of(value.toString()));
}

